# Build Asset bundle has been obsolete - Error getting when creating Asset bundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uct3.png)

C# Example
Builds an asset bundle from the selected objects in the project view.
Once compiled go to "Menu" -> "Assets" and select one of the choices
to build the Asset Bundle

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
public class ExportAssetBundles {
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundle From Selection - Track dependencies")]
    static void ExportResource () {
        // Bring up save panel
        string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel ("Save Resource", "", "New Resource", "unity3d");
        if (path.Length != 0) {
            // Build the resource file from the active selection.
            Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(Object), SelectionMode.DeepAssets);
            BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, selection, path, 
                                           BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets, BuildTarget.Android);
            Selection.objects = selection;
        }
    }
    [MenuItem("Assets/Build AssetBundle From Selection - No dependency tracking")]
    static void ExportResourceNoTrack () {
        // Bring up save panel
        string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel ("Save Resource", "", "New Resource", "unity3d");
        if (path.Length != 0) {
            // Build the resource file from the active selection.
            BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Selection.activeObject, Selection.objects, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither your question content nor its title make clear what kind of help you need. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"Unclear, your question is"_ - Yoda

Answer (score 3):

If you read the error message, it says that `UnityEditor.BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(Object, Object[], string, BuildAssesBundleOptions)` is obsolete and it suggests you should use the new AssetBundle system.

In Unity 5.4b, there are two overloads of BuildAssetBundles that are not obsolete.

`BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(string outputPath, BuildAssetBundleOptions assetBundleOptions, BuildTarget targetPlatform)`

**or**

`BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(string outputPath, AssetBundleBuild[] builds, BuildAssetBundleOptions assetBundleOptions, BuildTarget targetPlatform)`

Use one of these here and it should fix your problem.

**Lesson of the day: read error messages. They can help you a lot.**

Comment: thank you I do it but there is a new problem https://s17.postimg.org/dsf07s7lb/Capture.png